# From where we can set default values for swagger when you run

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm wondering how can I set default values in swagger, when you run the project, I thought it sets in the class like this:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Your spread percentage
 /// </summary>
 /// <example>12</example>
 public decimal ClassNumber { get; set; } = default!;
```

but its not working,there should be somewhere else to set the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom `ISchemaFilter` to modify your Example value:

**Note**: Not sure what is your *version of the Swagger*,different version of  swagger will make the parameter in `Apply()` different. I use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v 5.6.3`.

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public decimal ClassNumber { get; set; }
    //other properties...
}
```

CustomSchemaFilter :

```
public class CustomSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type == typeof(TestModel))
        {
            schema.Example = new OpenApiObject
            {
                ["ClassNumber"] = new OpenApiString("2.6"),
                //["ToDate"] = new OpenApiInteger(1)
                //other property in your model
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Register the filter in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebapiProject5", Version = "v1" });
    c.SchemaFilter<CustomSchemaFilter>();

});
```